Time regularity vs space regularity for parabolic PDE
Suppose that there exist separable Hilbert spaces $V, H, X$ such that $V\hookrightarrow H\hookrightarrow X\hookrightarrow  V'\,$ continuously, where $V'$ denotes the dual of the Hilbert space $V$. Let $T\in (0,\infty)$. Assume that
\begin{equation}
u\in L^2((0,T),V)\cap H^1((0,T),V'),\qquad f\in L^2((0,T),V')\,.
\end{equation}
I wonder if I can infer
\begin{equation}
u\in C((0,T),V)\cap C^1((0,T),V'),\qquad f\in C((0,T),X)\,.
\end{equation}
Indeed, I am trying to adapt Theorem 11.3 of M. Renardy, R.C. Rogers, An Introduction to Partial Differential Equations, Springer New York, NY, (2004).
Ultimately, using Lemma 11.4 of the same book, I would like to have
\begin{equation}
u\in C([0,T],H)\cap C((0,T),V)\cap C^1((0,T),V')\,.
\end{equation}
More precise question:
Let $Q\,:\, X\to X$  be a positive and injective operator.
Set $V= \text{dom}(Q)^{1/2}, V'=\text{dom}(Q)^{-1/2}$. Observe that $Q\,:\, V\to V'$ is bounded. Suppose that there exits a Hilbert space $H$ such that $V\hookrightarrow H\hookrightarrow X\hookrightarrow  V'\,$ continuously.
Let $t > 0$, assume $e^{-tQ}\,:\, X \to H$, $e^{-tQ}\,:\,X \to V$ and $e^{-tQ}\,:\,H \to V$ are semi-group contractions (it holds due to the smoothing property of the semigroup $e^{-t\,Q}$). Now consider
\begin{equation}\label{eq:SPDE_remainder}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t Y +Q \,Y= -f(Y)\,,~~~t>0
 \\
Y(0,\cdot) = y_0\in H\,,
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $f(Y)\in C([0,T), X)$ which implies $f(Y)\in C((0,T];V')$ as $H\hookrightarrow V'$. In particular, $f(Y)\,:\,H\to X$ is local Lipschitz continuous, i.e., $\|f(Y_1)-f(Y_2)\|_{X}\leq \,c\, \|Y_1-Y_2\|_{H}$ for some positive $c\in (0,\infty)$.
Using the Banach fixed point theorem, I showed that there exists a mild $H-$valued solution this equation on $[0,T]$ which is a function $Y\in C([0,T];H)$ satisfying the following integral equation
\begin{equation}
Y(t,\cdot) = e^{-tQ}\,y_0 -\int_0^{t}\,e^{-(t-s)Q} f(Y(s))\,ds\qquad\text{for all}\qquad0\leq t\leq T\,.
\end{equation}
Similarly, one verifies that there exists a mild $V-$valued solution on $(0,T]$ which is a function $Y\in C((0,T];V)$.
Using direct calculation, I verified
\begin{equation}\label{eq:solution}
 Y\in  
  C([0,T],H)\cap 
 C((0,T],V)\cap 
 C^1((0,T],V')\,.
\end{equation}
But I am interested in the idea behind such a setting, that is why I started thinking of Lion's theorem and I also found Theorem 11.3 of M. Renardy, R.C. Rogers book. I wonder if I can get my desired result using the mentioned theorem? or they are not related due to having a different regularity in time.

Could you maybe write down the PDE at hand?

Thank you for your comment. I just added more details.
